Install shower grab bar - 2x2 studs
I need to install some grab bars in the shower. I know where the studs are and I can access the back of two of the three walls to put blocking. The third wall is cinder block, 2x2 studs, drywall and tile and the studs are 16" on centre. I can't access the back of this wall, but, of course, this is where I need to put a 36" horizontal bar. Here is the cross section:

I've come up with three options.


I put one end on a stud, the other is in space. Due to the small studs, there is not much space in the wall (~2"). Not enough for a SecureMount Anchor (pic) which needs 3.5". Is there some other mounting product that fits in limited space?

I mount the bar at an angle. This is not what the user wants so I would consider this a last resort.

I make a plate out of stainless steel and attach securely to the wall. Drill and tap holes to mount the grab bar and use machine screws to mount the bar to the plate. Like this: 


Should I screw the plate into the studs, or through the studs and into the cinder block?
Is there any good mounting method I'm missing? If one side of the bar can be mounted into a stud, is the 2x2 strong enough? Should I be thinking of screwing into the cinder block (with longer concrete screws)?

It's a bit invasive, but can you drill big through the tile and then screw into the cinder block (with a sleeve that'll maintain the depth and not just smash the tile into the void)? You might also look at toggler brand fasteners, which ought to flip inside of 1.5", though you might have to oversize the hole a tiny bit. Last idea: shorter grab bars.

I would call 2x2's on top of concrete closer to furring strips than studs and would not count on them to hold unless I knew how they were attached to the concrete.

About how high off the shower floor will this bar be located?

I wouldn't consider those 2x2's as anything more than spacers, with little to no structural strength. Don't refer or even think about them as "studs"

@TigerGuy Agree 100% and exactly why I asked this. I didn't know what else to call them, but yeah I thought using them for strength was a poor move. The plan was always to go through them into the block, but what to do about the end in free space?

@brhans, Thanks for the additional comment. I think the same thing. They were in a wall and so I automatically went to 'stud' but should have used a different word.
